# position:absolute and z-index make the a link can't click?

Tags: css

http://down123.xxmn.com/wemade/

the navigation of all the `test`  links are can't click, the position:absolute and z-index caused it. if i don't delete the z-index. is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Your `#container` is covering your `#menu` because of the the `z-index` of `-10` you've given to your `#menu`

Answer (score 1):

Just did this with Firebug,so you have to remove the `z-index` in your `#menu` and that will solve the issue as you told, is there any specific reason you don't want to remove `z-index`?

Edit: If you are finding it hard to make your logo go behind the menu, than instead of giving `z-index: -10;` to `#menu` give `z-index: -1` to `#top` and it will solve your issue

Comment: i want to the id with top lay which locates at the right of the page behind the #menu lay.

Comment: @stack01 Sorry but am not getting your point, removing `z-index: -10;` is having no issues with other stuff

Comment: the bottom of the top image can see, if removing z-index: -10; the bottom of the image will behind the menu background color.

Comment: @stack01 Now i got you, I'll edit my answer too, add `z-index: -1;` in `#top` and remove the other `z-index: -10;` from `#menu`

Comment: now,if i want the  #top lay upon  the menu lay,how should i do? thank you